# How to get values of attributes on a XML file using C++?

Tags: c++, xml

Need to write some C++ code that reads  XML string and if i do

something like:
get valueofElement("ACTION_ON_CARD") it returns 3
get valueofElement("ACTION_ON_ENVELOPE") it returns YES

XML String:

```
<ACTION_ON_CARD>3</ACTION_ON_CARD>
<ACTION_ON_ENVELOPE>YES</ACTION_ON_ENVELOPE>
```

Any code example would be helpfull

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

writing an xml parser is not necessarily an easy thing to do, so unless it is a requirement you do it yourself I suggest you get a library to do that for you.

There are many available like [xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) (pretty complete but not exactly simple), [tinyxml](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/) (mostly the opposite of xerces, it probably suits best your needs) or [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/) (never tried this one)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the schema, you could use [codesynthesis](http://www.codesynthesis.com) xsd compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the XML parser from the Poco C++ library. It's well documented and easy to use.